# Calculating the probability that $X > Y$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Given two random variables, $X$ and $Y$ with support $(-\infty,\infty)$, I know that the probability that $X > Y$ can be calculated by their joint distribution $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ through integration:

$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^x_{-\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dy\ dx$

But can I use this method?

$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f_{X}(x)F_Y(x)\ dx$

Is this above correct?

Comment: It is true only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS if I change it to $\int^\infty_{-\infty}f_{X}(x)F_{Y|X = x}(x)\ dx$ is it correct for all X and Y then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent r.v., then 
$$
\int_{(-\infty, \infty)} \int_{(-\infty, x]} f_{X,Y}(x,y)= \int_{(-\infty, \infty)} \left(\int_{(-\infty, x]} f_Y(y)dy\right)f_X(x)dx = \int_{(-\infty, \infty)} F_Y(x)f_X(x)dx   .
$$

If not, then using the property that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y|X}(y)f_Y(y)$ you get that
$$
P(Y < X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dydx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_{Y|X=x}(x)f_X(x)dx.
$$
Namely,
$$
P(Y<X)=\int P(Y<X|X=x)f_X(x)dx = \int g(x)f_X(x)dx = E_Xg(X). 
$$

Comment: if I change it to $\int^\infty_{-\infty}f_{X}(x)F_{Y|X = x}(x)\ dx$ is it correct for all X and Y then?

Comment: Yes, I've added some details